# Run a program with the .exe out of main directory using batch files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe

I would like to know if it is possible with a batch file to run a .exe of say, a game outside of the main directory. The .exe would be in a totally different location then the files it is associated with.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "outside of the main directory." If you mean "can a batch script run files in differing locations on a Windows system" the answer is yes. You just want to use a relative or absolute path. See: http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net/shared/geoprocessing/sharing_tools_and_toolboxes/pathnames_explained_colon_absolute_relative_unc_and_url.htm

Comment: I think he means it such that the executable is able to find the associated files (.dlls, config, etc) in the game directory

Comment: pretty much i can not run a .exe program because there is a whitelist at my school. but one certain drive can run .exe files. so I was just wondering if it was possible to run .exe files on that drive that also takes the files on the white-listed drive.

Answer (score 1):

`start /B /WAIT /D <WorkingDir> <ExePath> <Parameters>`

http://asawicki.info/news_1501_how_to_run_windows_command_with_given_working_directory.html

Alternatively, if you don't NEED to use a batch file, creating a shortcut and setting the working directory from its properties also works